# How to find all the polkadot accounts with index or identity attached

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I want to find all the polkadot accounts which either have an index or have registered their identity; similar to https://polkascan.io/polkadot/account/identities and https://polkascan.io/polkadot/indices/account.

Answer (score 5):

Using JS, you can simply iterate over the storage items which track this information for all accounts.

For example, to get all accounts with some Identity information, you would do:

```
let users = await api.query.identity.identityOf.entries()
```

This will return all the different storage keys and values under the `identityOf` storage item. Those keys will have the `AccountId` as the last 32 bytes of the key.

```
> util_crypto.encodeAddress(users[0][0].slice(-32))

"5CMbC573hpNWhJVTe4Qo7AtFQntAQDWKKVX9kt9WAHGy413y"
```

```
> users[0][1].toJSON()


{…}
​
deposit: 1666666666660
​
info: Object { additional: [], display: {…}, legal: {…}, … }
​
judgements: Array [ (2) […] ]
```